# error from node js or npm when I open Ubuntu terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, node.js, npm

I get this error every time I open a terminal and I also can get it any time I try some command. I tried to fix it by removing node and npm completely from computer but it still shows up. I checked for the "internal/modules/cjs/loader.js" file using "locate" but I don't have it on my computer. This error showed up after I updated my Ubuntu to 18.04.3 LTS from Ubuntu 16 or 14, I can't remember exactly.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/rzone/bash'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

if I go to folder ~/Downloads

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/rzone/Downloads/bash'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

if I try the node command

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/rzone/Downloads/node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

same if I try the rvm command (I had installed the Ruby Version Manager before upgrading Ubuntu)

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/rzone/Downloads/bash'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: How exactly do you "open a terminal", and what has node got to do with it? If you start, say, an `xterm` from your window manager, node shouldn't be involved at all. If this happens in a particular application (say, Visual Studio), please edit your question.

Comment: I'm using gnome classic and I open the default GNOME Terminal v3.28.2, nothing related to Visual Studio or any other IDE. I don't know what node has got to do with, that is my problem. Seems magic to me that node is involved in this. I double checked any .profile .bashrc .bash_profile file and nothing unusual happens there.

Comment: Hey Razvan did you ever get and answer on this - I now have it?

Comment: @Kibi no, since then I deleted and reinstalled my ubuntu, after that I choose to work in a vbox instead of dual-boot